# Order Type to sell options a few days before the Expiration

Tags: options, call-options

With the stock at $175, a novice trader buys 1 call option:

- Option Price: $20
- Strike Price: $200
- Expiry: December 15, 2020
- Cost: $4,000

He wants to SELL TO CLOSE the option on **December 1st, 2020** end of day for whatever the market price.

I looked at this list of [order types](https://www.investopedia.com/investing/basics-trading-stock-know-your-orders/). What order type should the trader  choose?

**UPDATE**

The following order type is from etrade Powertrade. Will this serve the purpose?

The Duration available in the form are:

- Good For the Day
- Good Until Cancelled
- Good Until Date
- On the Open
- On the Close
- Immediate or Cancel
- Fill Or Kill

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Limit orders (buy, sell, buy stop, and sell stop)   allow an investor to buy and sell securities at a certain price in the future.

Some brokers offer complex conditional orders that allow application of logical conditions (greater than, less than, equal to) to a combinations of variables such as  price, time in force (day, GTC), volume, margin cushion, trade and percentage change, and the value of other securities.

I have never seen one that offers the ability to buy or sell on a predetermined  date in the future.

Comment: I updated the original post with a screenshot from etrade Powertrade order types. The duration selected is **GTD (Good Till Date)**.

Comment: All of those orders in your update  are Time In Force orders.  They specify that your order is good for right now, for the day, until a date in the future, etc. but none of them specify that the order be filled on such and such date.

Comment: Does that mean if an order is created with first three options, the order will be executed immediately as soon as the market opens?

Comment: All of those orders in your update  are Time In Force orders.  They specify that your order is good for right now, for the day, until a date in the future, etc. but none of them specify that the order be filled on such and such date.